# Union of two tables with same columns using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm new to sqlalchemy and am wondering how to do a union of two tables that have the same columns. I'm doing the following:

```
table1_and_table2 = sql.union_all(self.tables['table1'].alias("table1_subquery").select(),
self.tables['table2'].alias("table2_subquery").select())
```

I'm seeing this error:

> OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1248, 'Every derived table must have its own alias')

(Note that `self.tables['table1']` returns a sqlalchemy `Table` with name *table1*.)

Can someone point out the error or suggest a better way to combine the rows from both tables?

Answer (score 0):

First, can you output the SQL generated that creates the problem? You should be able to do this by setting `echo=True` in your `create_engine` statement.

Second, and this is just a hunch, try rearranging your subqueries to this:

```
table1_and_table2 = sql.union_all(self.tables['table1'].select().alias("table1_subquery"),
    self.tables['table2'].select().alias("table2_subquery"))
```

If my hunch is right it's creating aliases, then running a query and the resulting query results are re-aliased and clashing